# Enabling the VT-x inside a virtual machine

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtualization, ubuntu-10.04

I work in Ubuntu from Oracle Virtual Machine which is installed on top of Windows.

I have activated the VT-x feature in the host BIOS. After this I created a new virtual machine with VT-x and EPT enabled.

Now I run

```
$ egrep '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo
```

from the guest to check if the vmx feature is enabled and the answer is 0, i.e. not enabled.

How can I enable this feature on the guest VM?

Comment: 1. You have to ask on another site. 2. Enable it in the VM settings. 3. ditch windows and run Ubuntu directly instead.

Comment: I think it's off topic here

Answer (score 3):

@asked There are three most common reasons for this error:

- Your CPU doesn’t support VT-x or AMD-V virtualization
- VT-x or AMD-V is not enabled in BIOS (UEFI)
- You have Hyper-V virtualization enabled in Windows

Answer (score 2):

You can't enable VT-x inside Virtualbox. There's a ticket for it that hasn't been fixed yet

> [Edit by klaus 2018-05-06:]
>
> This feature is being worked on for a while. Once the implementation is complete and tested it will be available to all users.
>
> [[feature-request] Nested Virtualization: VT-in-VT](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/4032)

It's possible to run nested VMs with Hyper-V and VMWare ESX or ESXi though

- [Run Hyper-V in a Virtual Machine with Nested Virtualization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/nested-virtualization)
- [How to enable VT-X on VM](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/490355)
- [Is it possible to use VMX CPU instructions inside VM?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42597774/995714)
- [How to enable VT-x inside a Virtual Machine inside a Virtual Machine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50529214/995714)
- [Is it possible to setup a virtual machine inside another virtual machine](https://serverfault.com/q/46960/343888)
- [How to run VMWare ESX or ESXi in a virtual machine?](https://serverfault.com/q/28399/343888)
- [Nested virtualization - is it possible?](https://serverfault.com/q/761233/343888)

However [it does need EPT to run](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2034803). Make sure your host CPU has EPT support. Without EPT you can only run 32-bit VMs using binary translation

> - Intel VT-x or AMD-V is required for running “Nested Virtualization” which supports nested 32-bit VMs
> - Intel EPT or AMD RVI is required for running nested 64-bit VMs.
>
> https://www.virtuallyghetto.com/2012/08/how-to-enable-nested-esxi-other.html

Some hypervisors do refuse to run if it found out that it's running inside a virtual machine or in a virtual machine some levels deep. That said, it's possible to run arbitrarily deep nested virtual machines using binary translation or an [emulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emulator) like Bochs or qemu

- [Can you run a machine emulator (Bochs) inside a virtual machine?](https://superuser.com/q/312433/241386)

Answer (score 1):

Both on Windows and Linux you can manage the VMs from the command line using **VBoxManage** tool as long as the Vt-d is enabled in the BIOS. I'm not clear on why the nested-VTX function in the VirtualBox VM parameter appears "uncheckable" or unavailable anyhow. I've found this command very handy for the case:

VBoxManage modifyvm [name_of_vm] --nested-hw-virt on

After that you can verify at parameters>system>processor how VT-x is indeed activated.