# How to enable VT-x inside a Virtual Machine inside a Virtual Machine

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, ubuntu-16.04

I have a windows 10 host operating system that supports virtualization. Next, I have an Ubuntu 16.04 virtual machine I created using virtualbox. For development purposes, I need to create a virtual machine inside my guest Ubuntu virtual machine. Unfortunately, I can't enable VT-x option in my guest Ubuntu machine to create a create a virtual machine inside my Ubuntu guest. Any information on how enable VT-x option on my virtual box inside my virtual Ubuntu machine would be appreciated.

Edit: I had that this may be accomplished through PCI Passthrough for VirtualBox. If so please detail how.
Lastly, my problem is similar to this [guy's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44003416/run-64bit-ubuntu-on-virtualbox-guest?rq=1) but with exception I can't seem to create an UBuntu32bit box.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enabling the VT-x inside a virtual machine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24340272/995714)

Answer (score 0):

> Any information on how enable VT-x option on my virtual box inside my virtual Ubuntu machine would be appreciated.

You simply **CAN'T**.

[VT-x is a hardware capability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization):

> In 2006, both Intel (VT-x) and AMD (AMD-V) introduced limited hardware virtualization support that allowed simpler virtualization software but offered very few speed benefits. Greater hardware support, which allowed substantial speed improvements, came with later processor models.

Since VT-x requires hardware capabilities to work, there's no way for the "outer" virtual machine in your nested VMs to provide that capability to the "inner" VM.  The "outer" VM doesn't have any actual hardware.

If you have to run a VM inside your VM that requires some of the capabilities that VT-x provides - such as the ability to run a 64-bit OS - you can try [QEMU](https://www.qemu.org/) for the "inner" virtual machines.  It'll be slower since it's an emulator and not true virtualization, though.

Comment: Now correct if I am wrong, but I heard it might be possible if through PCI passthrough for virtualbox?

Comment: @Sam I've never heard that, so I can't really comment on it.  Do you have any references?  I went through a similar problem a few months ago - I had been using an "inner" Centos VirtualBox VM on an "outer" Windows 10 VM (customer AWS instance) to support a small bit of Linux code. After what were probably Meltdown/Spectre patches to the "outer" Windows 10 VM, trying to start a VirtualBox VM would crash the Windows 10 instance instantly. I got quite familiar with futile efforts in trying to run a VM-in-a-VM at that point, and eventually just fell back to QEMU.

Comment: As you said VT-x enables hardware virtualization on guest Os so it can't be enabled on a nested VM. However, by allowing my VM to enable PCI Passthrough, my guest vm should able to access the PCI's on my host computer which might allow my VM to support that feature, VT-x. At least, so I have been told. I really told have a choice, I have to use VirtualBox for this problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: there's [EPT](https://www.anandtech.com/show/2480/10) to [run nested VMs though](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Level_Address_Translation) although I don't know if it exposes the VT-x feature to the VM or not